# Images upload: is it changed?

Tags: bug, user-interface, images

What is changed in the upload of images? I can not upload with my old MacBook! Or simply I have some connection problem?

when I click on the image icon a pop up is open with the words ''Click Here to upload your image'' but when I click it nothing happens.

I'm using Safari 5.0.6 on a Mac osX version 10.5.8

Comment: Unless you give a better description of what happens when you try to upload an image it is unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: when I click on the image icon a pop up is open with the words ''Click Here to upload your image'' but when I click it  nothing happens.

Comment: Okay that description should be edited into the question. I would assume that you are using some version of Safari, but at any rate the browser and version number should also go into your question. Also, this appears to be more of a bug report, so retagging it [meta-tag:bug] might be a good step so that the devs see it and can then try to reproduce it to diagnose and fix/give advice. (Well, I'll do the retagging.)

Comment: Thank you! I add the informations to my question.

Comment: Safari 5 is around 5 years old now, SE generally only supports somewhat current browsers. I'd recommend to install another current browser like Firefox and trying it again.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it! But it does not like to change something that works well just because someone has decided that it is old! ( I too  I'm old ...)